# How i use jest.useFakeTimers().setSystemTime()?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Property 'setSystemTime' does not exist on type 'typeof jest'.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue, all I needed to do was to update the jest and faker packages.